# Do not wait for for class instance to initialize and continue with the code c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, methods

I'm quite new with programming so the question might look stupid for you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
   driver[i] = new ChromeDriver(service, options[i]);
}
```

I'm trying to make a webbot. It has to open multiple chrome windows (which works fine)

the part when he opens Chrome is on line 3. Each opening takes like 5-6 seconds.

So my question is, when I initialize a new instance of ChromeDriver, can I continue with the initialization of another ChromeDriver instance (or with other code) even if the first initialization is not done?

tldr; how to initialize multiple instances at the same time if the initialization takes time.

I appreciate any help

Comment: if the platform allows it, read up on multi-threading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run multiple threads in C#, which means that you can run your code in parallel, not waiting for one method to complete for other to run.

The recommended way to do that is using methods from `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace, most notably `Task.Run`.

Though in your case I would recommend to think of parallel for:

```
Parallel.For(0, 20, i =>
    {
       driver[i] = new ChromeDriver(service, options[i]);
    });
```

Comment: Hi Ivan,
thanks for your answer.

if i make an async method i would need to give her a ChromeDriver as parameter and it would return the ChromeDriver.

but how can I give her a Chromedriver which is not initialised. and since i am really new with c# and async is a hard part of programming i cant use it unleast you tell me exactly how or where to look up how it would work for this specifc case

Comment: You may use parallel for, that seems to be the simplest solution for you - just by adding parallel to for it will work like what you requested.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Task.Run

```
var task = Task.Run(() => new ChromeDriver(service, options[i]));
```

The overall code will look like this:

```
var taskList = new List<Task>(20);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
   var task = new ChromeDriver(service, options[i]);
   taskList.Add(task);
}

//at the and wait all tasks to finish.
await Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

Comment: ChromeDriver is not a task (so it has no return).

in your code "task" is a new instance of ChromeDriver